# Why when multiplying fractions (by a whole number) you don't change the denominators?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

I need this information for a fraction project I need to do and I also am confused. Do you only multiply the numerators and denominators when finding equivlant fractions?

Comment: When you multiply two fractions $\dfrac{a}{b}$ and $\dfrac{x}{y}$ together the result is $\dfrac{ax}{by}$.  This is how multiplication of fractions was **defined** in the first place. 
 When you multiply the fraction $\dfrac{a}{b}$ and the whole number $x$ together, remembering that $x = \dfrac{x}{1}$, we recognize then that this is the same as multiplying $\dfrac{a}{b}$ and $\dfrac{x}{1}$ together and so we have $\dfrac{ax}{b\cdot 1}$ or simply $\dfrac{ax}{b}$

Comment: As for multiplying numerator *and* denominator, that is just a fancy way of multiplying by $1$.  Remembering that $\dfrac{a}{b}\cdot 1 = \dfrac{a}{b}$ and that $1 = \dfrac{x}{x}$, you see then that $\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{a}{b}\cdot 1 = \dfrac{a}{b}\cdot \dfrac{x}{x}=\dfrac{ax}{bx}$

Comment: This can't be real.

Comment: @Whatup1067 You are not very talkative, contrasting to what you say about you...